# Choose file window in extension firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

Iam building an extension and i want to take the path of a file from a window popup like windows does . Is something like that to use in an extension in firefox?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Open_and_Save_Dialogs)

**Creating a file picker**

To begin, you need to create a file picker component and initialize it.

```
var nsIFilePicker = Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker;
var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
fp.init(window, "Select a File", nsIFilePicker.modeOpen);
```

> First, a new file picker object is created and stored in the variable
>   'fp'. The 'init' function is used to initialize the file picker. This
>   function takes three arguments, the window that is opening the dialog,
>   the title of the dialog and the mode. The mode here is modeOpen which
>   is used for an Open dialog. You can also use modeGetFolder and
>   modeSave for the other two modes. These modes are constants of the
>   nsIFilePicker interface.

**Getting the selected file**

> Finally, you can show the dialog by calling the show() function. It
>   takes no arguments but returns a status code that indicates what the
>   user selected. Note that the function does not return until the user
>   has selected a file. The function returns one of three constants:
>
> **returnOK** - the user selected a file and pressed OK. The file the user
>   selected will be stored in the file picker's file property.
>
> **returnCancel** - the user pressed Cancel.
>
> **returnReplace** - in the save
>   mode, this return value identifies that the user selected a file to be
>   replaced. (returnOK will be returned when the user entered the name of
>   a new file.) You should check the return value and then get the file
>   object from the file picker using the file property.

```
var res = fp.show();
if (res != nsIFilePicker.returnCancel){
  var thefile = fp.file;
  // --- do something with the file here ---
}
```